# Fast way to send data from homepage to console program

Tags: json, signalr, asp.net-web-api

I transfer data from MVC- homepage to af console program with web API like this:

- Get data from MSSQL via Entity Framework.
- Serialize data to json.
- through Newtonsoft Json. Zip data. send it to console.
- Unzip data.
- Deserialize data.
- Read it in to my data model and use data.

I have quit a lot of data and it takes 7 seconds just to serialize data.
Is there a faster way to transact data?

Perhaps as xml or through SignalR?

I have looked at ServiceStack to serialize json, which should be quicker, but my data is hierarch, which Newtonsoft handles very well with PreserveReferencesHandling.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Kind regards from Kenneth

Answer (score 0):

I decided to handle this isue by serializing to binary instead of json.

It has brought me down from a load time on 6 seconds to 0,3 seconds.
My data has a lot of self-references that was time consuming for the json serialization.

Now I have marked all my objects with [Serializable].

Then I serialize to a binary format that I can zip and then stream through API to my console.

The serializer:

```
public static byte[] CompressBinary(object value)
{
        byte[] result;
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, value);
            stream.Position = 0;
            result = CompressStream(stream);
        }
        return result;
}
```

Please tell me if any has better sugestions.